# Post json string to ElasticSearch through webrequest c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I want to post json data to elasticsearch through web request. I get bad request for the below code.   Added stack trace logs.

```
        string responseFromServer = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9200/test/test");
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        string username = "aaa";
        string password = "aaa";
        string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Stacktrace:

```
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at APIResponse.Program.posttoelk(String json) in Program.cs:line 85
   at APIResponse.Program.Main(String[] args) in :line 50
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What error do you get in the ES log?

Comment: I get bad request error.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: In ES log, i could see index created but not data.

Comment: I'm interested in the stack trace you see in the ES logs, not the C# one.

Comment: [2016-11-22T00:12:54,790][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [gCmY5Sd] [test] creating index, cause [auto(index api)], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []

Comment: That's not an error, simply an INFO log stating that the index was created. What comes after that which causes a bad request error to be thrown?

Comment: no errors logged as such

Comment: JSON format is wrong. Fixed the bad request issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran some code that was highly similar to what you did above and it worked for much of my dataset [1].  Because of that, I *think* the code you have above is fine.  From my limited examination, it appeared some of my JSON objects were failing because they weren't properly escaped.

I don't think you are showing us the contents of the json variable in your statement:

```
           streamWriter.Write(json);
```

In line with what I said above, the JSON you are attempting to write in the streamWrite.Write statement may be malformed or improperly escaped.  I suggest you set a breakpoint at the above mentioned line and examine the contents of the json variable in the Visual Studio debugger to make sure your JSON is indeed valid.

If you have access to Kibana, I suggest you open the Kibana Dev Tools and post the contents of your json variable there according to section "6.2 Insert some data to index" of 
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/elasticsearch-and-kibana-installation-and-basic-usage-on-ubuntu-1604/

When you POST your JSON via Kibana, you will immediately get feedback on whether or not your JSON is correctly formed or not.  During exploratory testing, I feel Kibana is a little easier to use than GNU/Linux Curl statements or MS PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod commands.

Lastly, when working with C#, it may be easier to just use the Elastic Search NEST API and POCOs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/nest-quick-start.html#_indexing
I don't think I'm going to go this route, but for some people, it may be a better long term solution.

[1] - While many of my JSON objects did *not* get indexed, many of my other JSON objects *did* get indexed.  I think this was because some of my JSON objects were also malformed or improperly escaped.